# What is the difference between these declaration of stack, stack<int> and stack<int*>?

Tags: c++, stl, stack

```
stack<int*>
```

vs

```
stack<int>
```

I am stuck in this kindly help if you know the Answer.

Comment: Context would be nice.. so far it's typeid versus template's name, that's all

Comment: One stores `int`s with stars. The other stores `int`s. Any [non-fraudulent C++ programming text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) will tell you what the star means in the first few pages.

Comment: Do you know about pointers? And what `int*` means? It means nothing different when used as template parameter.

Comment: Obviously you haven't learned yet about pointers. This is a good thing, but you have a whole world of pain ahead of you.

Answer (score 3):

`int` is a type. It is an integer type.

`int*` is a compound type. It is a pointer to an object of type `int`.

`stack<T>` is instantiation of a template named `stack`. The angle brackets denote the list of template arguments passed to the instantiation.

`stack<int>` is instantiation of the template for the type `int`.

`stack<int*>` is instantiation of the template for the type `int*`.